# AnimationSet setInterpolator() not working wen using nineoldandroids lib

Tags: android, animation, interpolation

I am using Jake Wharton's nineoldandroids lib for implementing animations compatible with pre Honeycomb devices.
the lib: http://nineoldandroids.com/

for some reason, setting an AnimationSet interpolator does not seem to work.
I googled it and I did not find any reference to using setInterpolator() with nineoldandroids (nothing that either confirms or denies setInterpolator() support)

Does anyone know if it is supported? and if it is, is there a certain way I should use it to make it work?

Code example:

```
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
set.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());

set.playTogether(
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", 100f)
);

set.setDuration(1000).start();
```

It does not matter what interpolator I set, it is always using AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Late, but I just ran into the same issue.

You have to call `setInterpolator()` after you've added the animations (after `playTogether()` or similar), because it'll only apply the interpolator to animations in the AnimationSet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but I tried setting the interpolator on each ObjectAnimator and it worked. When I tried setting it on the AnimatorSet, it didn't.